# copying files from data/data/files/

Tags: android, image, save

I have a jpeg file created on this location `/data/data/appname/files`. 
I want it to be saved in the gallery of the user as a viewable picture. (internal memory preferred)

How do i go about it ?

(I am new at this , so please be elaborated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this what you want?

1.decode bitmap from file

```
            Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
```

2.save image to gallery

```
     MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

And save image to internal memory:

```
String filePath = mContext.getCacheDir()+"YOUR_FILE_NAME";
File file = new File(filePath);
FileOutputStream os = null;
try {
     os = new FileOutputStream(file);
     if (null != os) {
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
     os.flush();
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: it is showing error 
Failed to create thumbnail,removing original

Comment: post the stacktrace please/

Comment: the location of my image is data/data/appname/files/
where to get the stack trace from ?

Comment: what is it ,tell me where to get it from ?

Comment: 08-15 15:56:01.805: W/MediaProvider(161): original file hasn't been stored yet: /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1376562361801.jpg
08-15 15:56:01.825: E/MediaStore(18388): Failed to create thumbnail, removing original

Comment: did you add your permission in AndroidManifest.xml?    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

Comment: could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: okay, i got it working
i used this instead of what you gave 

 Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("data/data/com.example.paint/files/diagonal.jpg");

Comment: and , is there any way to save to the phone memory instead of sd card ?

Comment: so so sorry, the decode option i post is wrong. we should just remove the option

Comment: internal memory is the data/data/appname/

Comment: no, i mean, the above code is saving in the sd card
what to do to make it save to internal memory

Comment: two = s in the same line ?